# Difference between shouldComponentUpdate and built-in diffing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that `shouldComponentUpdate()` will prevent calling `render()` method if it returns false.
If I use some expensive logic in `render()` method, then `shouldComponentUpdate()` is a really helpful thing, because I can prevent `render()` call.

But what if my `render()` method returns only `Element`, without executing any expensive code.

Is there any difference between comparison( let's take PureComponent's implementation ) in `shouldComponentUpdate()` and built-in React diffing while `render()` call?

Comment: Just mentioning that `PureComponent` has a loop of conditions (Shallow) that checks whether the props has changed - Consider that this also cost performance, sometimes even more than without it. So, it really depends on your specific case.

Comment: Depends on what `Element` is. You need to use benchmarks to estimate whether `shouldComponentUpdate` is justified. This is always done like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is great written here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

The main diffrence is that React.PureComponent does a shallow comparison between old props and new props and between old state and new state, but the built-in React diffing(reconcilation) briefly is comparing down the old and new DOM tree, but please read this article above, it will resolve your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

React tells you to avoid at maximum scenarios, this will cause a performance issues.
React is very smart at updating the component elements, use `key`  where you need to, react will match the updates and update the DOM. React itself does the comparison of the previous and new props and update the dom.

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output
>   is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default
>   behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast
>   majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.

As per react component will re-render only if the state is changed.

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on
>   it to “prevent” a rendering, as this can lead to bugs. Consider using
>   the built-in PureComponent instead of writing shouldComponentUpdate()
>   by hand. PureComponent performs a shallow comparison of props and
>   state, and reduces the chance that you’ll skip a necessary update.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

If you still want to use that you need to measure downside and upside for this. I think you should avoid it completely, because there are higher chances that you might mess up the things by comparing.

Answer (score 0):

ShouldComponentUpdate() in the PureComponent's will do shallow comparison of current and previous props and state.
which skip the whole rendering process, including calling render() on this component and below.
Which totally avoids the Reconciliation process. which means that react don't have to update the V-DOM and no need to compare against real DOM. Which is expensive task compared with shallow comparison.